# Select rows based on 2 column combination

Tags: hive

I've a table with the following (partial) structure:

```
id_1 score_1 id_2 score_2
77    10    88   50
77    10    88   30
77    25    88   50
77    25    88   30
```

meaning, `id` can get more than one score.
What I want is to leave the rows where the `id`'s combination is with the maximum `score` of each `id`.

In the above-mentioned example, I'd like to leave only the following row:

```
id_1 score_1 id_2 score_2
77    25    88   50
```

I tried to use *self-join* methods, but with no success.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the combinations, you will need to perform a full join, depending on your Hive configuration you could need set the following property

```
set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict
```

This query will work for your case.  DEMO:

```
create table tmp3 
(
id_1 string, score int, id_2 string, score_2 int

);

INSERT INTO TABLE tmp3
VALUES (77, 10,    88,   50),(77  ,  10   , 88  , 30),(77  ,  25  ,  88 ,  50),(77  ,  25  ,  88 ,  30);

select a.id_1, a.score, b.id_2,b.score_2 from 
(
select id_1, max(score) as score from tmp3 group by id_1
) a
full join 
(
select id_2, max(score_2) as score_2 from tmp3 group by id_2

) b;
```

result

```
a.id_1,a.score,b.id_2,b.score_2
77,25,88,50
```

By the way, depending on your data size and the distribution of your ID's, the fulljoin could take several time ..

UPDATE: 
Updating answer to use window function alllowing selecting multiple columns for max scores

```
select a.id_1, a.score, b.id_2,b.score_2 from 
(
select id_1, score from (
select id_1,  score , 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by id_1 order by score desc) AS row_num
from tmp3
) x1 where row_num = 1
) a
full join 
(
select id_2, score_2 from (
select id_2,  score_2  ,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by id_2 order by score_2 desc) AS row_num
from tmp3
) x2 where row_num = 1

) b;
```

Comment: @halgos Thank for your answer. With your permission, I'd like to ask you one more thing. As I mentioned in my question, I added only partial structure of my table, and when I'm trying to implement your answer with more than one column (for example: `select id_1, amount, max(score) as score from tmp3 group by id_1, amount`) I'm not getting what I need (assume that `amount` is not fixed value). I believe I need something like `over` and `partition by`, but I can't resolve this issue. I'll be happy to hear if you have solution to this problem.

Comment: @staove7 I updated the answer using window functions to select more than 1 column. it should work.

Comment: Wow.. Thank you very much for your help!!